# Use move semantics and vector of references to children of abstract classes

Tags: c++, class, oop, move-semantics, raii

I'm trying (unsuccesfully) to create a vector of objects and use polimophism without manual memory management and any kind of pointers (*, unique_ptr, shared_ptr, weak_ptr, etc) relying on raii idiom.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct A{
    virtual void foo()=0;
    virtual ~A(){}
};
struct C:A{
    int bar;
    C(int bar):bar(bar){}
    virtual void foo(){
        cout << bar << endl;
    }
    virtual ~C(){}
};
struct B:A{
    vector<A> &&bar;
    int f;
    B(int f, vector<A> bar):f(f),bar(bar){}
    B(int f, vector<A> &bar):f(f),bar(bar){}
    B(int f, vector<A> &&bar):f(f), bar(bar){}
    virtual void foo(){
        cout << f << endl;
        for(auto &f: bar){
            f.foo();
        }
    }
    virtual ~B(){}
};

int main() {
    B b{1, vector<A>{C{1},C{2}}};
    b.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't compiles. What do I do wrong?

Comment: What is *"`vector<A> &&bar;`*" supposed to be?

Comment: an rvalue reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<A> something
```

is a vector which dynamically allocates storage for `A`, and only `A`, when objects are added.

The storage type of the vector is `A`, it stores instances of `A`.

When you push the first `C` onto it, it does something along the lines of:

```
void push_back(const A& a)  // NOTE: A, not C, downcasting occurs
{
    // extreme aproximation
    if (something.begin_ == nullptr) {
      something.begin_ = new A;
      something.begin_[0] = a;  // A::operator=(const A&);
      something.capacity_ = something.end_ = something.begin_ + 1;
    } else {
      ..
    }
}
```

Because `C` inherits from `A` it is able to downcast to this. However, it is only going to copy the `A` portion of the object passed to it, because the storage type of the vector *is `A`* and so your `int bar` in `C` is not copied.

This is called slicing, and the only way around it is either dynamic (pointers or std::any), or the perilous path of using a union.

-- Edit --

A secondary issue is what you expect `std::vector<A> &&bar` to do? The temporary objects to which it references expires at the end of the constructor expression:

```
B b{1, vector<A>{C{1},C{2}}};  // temporary vector is destroyed
// b.bar is dangling rvalue reference
```

-- Edit 2 --

Your question title contains "use move semantics" but as mentioned in edit 1, you only store an rvalue *reference*. Move semantics are about transferance: consider this simple `strdup` wrapper:

```
struct Strdupper {
    char* str_;
    Strdupper() = delete;
    Strdupper(const char* str) : str_(strdup(str)) {}
    ~Strdupper() { if (str_) free(str_); }
    Strdupper(const Strdupper& rhs) { str_ = strdup(rhs.str_); }
    Strdupper(Strdupper&& rhs) str_(rhs.str_) { rhs.str_ = nullptr; }
    Strdupper& operator=(const Strdupper& rhs) { if (str_) free(str_); str_ = strdup(rhs.str_); return *this; }
    Strdupper& operator=(Strdupper&& rhs) { std::swap(str_, rhs.str_); return *this; }
    // ...
};
```

Instead of an rvalue reference, your class B needs to actually store the vector and `std::move` the input parameter value to its constructor to call it's move-constructor:

```
class B {
    std::vector<X> vec_;

public:
    B() = default;
    B(const std::vector<X>& vec) : vec_(vec) {}  // copy semantics
    B(std::vector<X>&& vec) : vec_(std::move(vec)) {}  // move semantics
};
```

Comment: Your `Strdupper::operator=(const Strdupper&)` leaks memory.

Comment: @aschepler Whoops, fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why should we use std::move in constructor if we get rvalue reference?

Comment: @KOLANICH Because `std::vector<X>&& vec` *receives* an rvalue parameter but becomes an lvalue because we give it a name. If we removed the `std::move(vec)` we would be passing an *lvalue* to `vector`s constructor and copying rather than moving. `std::move` doesn't do anything, it just returns an rvalue-reference to the thing you pass it.